# Booster Circuit Output Capacitor Heating

Tags: pcb, boost, heat

I designed a booster circuit as shown in the figure. This circuit is charging a 16V 4700uF capacitor. Then the H-bridge is connected to the circuit.

I coded for the circuit and ran it. The H-bridge worked as I wanted, and my motor worked well.

After a while, the output capacitor C17 and one of the P-MOS got hot. I replaced these components with new ones, but when I connected the battery, the same components got hot again. What could be the cause of the heating?

[image]

Comment: What's the voltage rating of C17? What's the saturation current of L1?

Comment: 50V 4.7uF %10 tolerance 1206-case MLCC, current of L1 is 1.9A

Comment: What’s your load?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you copied the circuit from TI's application note for 12V/500mA boost regulator.

- They designed the circuit for max 500 mA output current
- The 4u7/50V capacitor they used is a 1210-case MLCC, so presumably its current-vs-temperature performance could be better than 1206s or 0805s.

So, make sure the output current does not go beyond 500 mA, and C17 can handle the inductor ripple currents. Capacitive loads (like the 4m7/16V you have) sometimes can be troublesome for DC-DC converters as the converter's behaviour may change.

Comment: The capacitor C17 I'm using is 1206-case capacitor. I guess I should try a 1210 case capacitor like you said. But before, I will measure the output current again. To mention the capacitive load, I can't do anything for that. I have to run my motor at 12V and I don't know any other solution...

Comment: Something is going wrong for me. When I connected the battery to the circuit, battery voltage drops from 3.6V to 1.5V. I am measuring a current equal to the current of the battery (200mA)(No capacitive or other loads). When I give 1 or 0 to the SHDN pin, the output current does not change.

Comment: I rebuilt the circuit with new components and there is no problem now. Is there any chance of damaging the IC when the motor is on and off?

Comment: @harmonica the start up currents (or loaded start ups) might cause to exceed the IC's max switch current, 1.5A, which "may or may not" result in permanent damage. Remember that switch current and output current are completely different things.

Comment: While removing all the components from the PCB one by one, I noticed that there was a short circuit between the 12V and GND. The problem is in the H-bridge circuit. I think I chose the wrong transistor or mosfet... Thanks for the extra information you provided