# Unexpected capacitor charging in booster circuit

Tags: capacitor, boost

In [a previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/643608/booster-circuit-output-capacitor-heating), I asked about an issue in this booster circuit.

[image: schematic]

I resolved that issue.

However, I have another problem. There is a 16V 4700uF capacitor *(not shown in the schematic)* at the output of the circuit and this capacitor charges up to 3.6V *(input voltage of the booster)* when the booster circuit is **not active**.

1. Is this because of the inductor?
2. I think I can isolate the circuit from the input voltage by using an external MOSFET, but can I solve this problem without using a MOSFET?

Comment: The 4700 uF capacitor will draw only leakage current. Look at the data sheet and see what this current is. It should be very small.

Comment: As Andy says, the capacitor will charge through D!. At very low currents - such as the leakage current of the 4700 uF capacitor, the drop across D1 will be small and Vout will approach Vbat. As current increases to the several mA range diode drop will rise. If Vout is almost the same as Vbat then the current must be small.

Comment: I'm a moderator: Each question should stand alone. It is a good idea to provide a link to any prior related question(s), as you have done. || Including the relevant schematic in a new question allows people to understand the question without having to look elsewhere. || In this case you say "There is a 16V 4700uF capacitor (not shown in the schematic) at the output of the circuit ." Presumably this is electrically in parallel with C17. Stating that explicitly would make it certain what was intended. (This is not essential - just helps people help you).

Comment: In shutdown R8 will draw I= V/R = 3.6/51000 =~ 70 uA.  This is about 10% of eg [this](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDE0000/ABA0000C1181.pdf) capacitor family  at 4700 uF 16V - but worth being aware of  At 3.6V cap leakage is probably more like 100 uA - so R8 current is significant.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to explain about R8. Actually there was a problem with the value of the R8 resistor. When I used the 51K resistor value, some current flowed to the SHDN pin and therefore the booster was always active. I replaced the R8 resistor with 100K, it doesn't seem to be a problem now. (Datasheet says 51K~100K)

Comment: Currently, I still measure 3.6V voltage on the capacitor(4700uF and parallel with C17) at the output when the booster is not active. Sorry but I couldn't understand the relation between R8 and output capacitor.

Comment: (1) 3.6V - Diode D1 will drop voltage at operating currents. If it is a Schottky diode  then it will drop typically 0.3v or more. If it is a silicon diode then 0.6V or more. IF the capacitor is at 3.6V then D1 is dropping very very little current as Vd1 ~= 0V. SO the capacitor is not wasting much battery energy. 2. R8: R8 also wastes battery energy.  If R8 = 100k then it will sink about 36uA to ground if Vshdn is 0V. This MAY be more than the output capacitor is wasting.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A voltage boost circuit produces a voltage that is higher than the input voltage so, if your input voltage is 3.6 volts, it cannot produce an output lower than this (minus the volt drop of the diode). The clue is in the name "booster". If you wish to be able to disengage the output from feeding the capacitor that you mention then, you will need to add another MOSFET or similar mechanism. Basic boost circuit: -

[image]

As you can see in the diagram [from my basic website](http://stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html), the lowest voltage on the output is V<sub>IN</sub> - 0.7 volts because, with the MOSFET deactivated, the output connects to the input supply via the inductor and diode.

Comment: If my 16V 4700uF capacitor at the output will stay constant at 3.6V when the booster is not active, then my battery life will be affected a lot :/ I'll think about the idea of ​​adding another MOSFET. Thanks!